# How to improve performance

Tags: java, html

This is my current condition ,

I have input date and process button . This process button for generate report day for the date I input. For generate 1 report day in need 3-20 mins. This method really tired when i must generate 1 month report , i must input date 1 by 1 from 1 to 30.

Because of that i using "Days.daysBetween" from joda time library to help me. I have no problem using joda to get the day or for the looping.

My problem is : If i input date from 1 - 30. After each day report **the performance is down**. If i manually input for 1 day , i need 3-20 mins, but when i using this method after day 10 , i need until 1 hour to complete 1 day.

Any solution for my problem?

FYI : for generate 1 day report, i need to work against 40-60k records , calculate and put in 4 tables.

Lib what i using:
JodaTime

this is my current code (using this method , if i put from = 1 Jan 2015 , until = 31 Jan 2015. After 10 Jan 2015,  i need to wait until 1 hour to finish 1 looping)  :

```
List<Date> dateList = methodFromJodaCalculateIt(fromDate , untilDate);
for(Date d : dateList){
  generateReport1(d);
  generateReport2(d);
  generateReport3(d);
  generateReport4(d);
}
```

But, if i didn't use looping for , only :

```
generateReport1(inputDate);
generateReport2(inputDate);
generateReport3(inputDate);
generateReport4(inputDate);
```

i only need up to 20 mins to finish  all 4 report.

Thank You before

Comment: Is that the actual code? I don't see your date getting passed in anywhere in the code you provided. It might also be important for us to see (roughly) what's going on in your code to actually generate the report.

Comment: Also, it might be worth your time to run this code within VisualVM to see what's going on where. We can only speculate at what might be causing a problem, but with a profiler it can often be seen what is causing the problem.

Comment: Does these report generation is asynchronous?

Comment: @Dogs yes that is actual code. only looping for as much as the date. In each generateReport they query to table , group by, calculate that , count this that put in 1 table.

Comment: @N K , yes this report generation is asynchronous. I using EventBus from google. So i just post from and until date , and there is subscriber call that method.